# Rspec not finding committed changes to an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i'm new to rspec and ruby...

i have the following code in one of course_rspec.rb

...
  it "check for active courses after enabling a course" do
    course = Course.create(:title => "Testing", :description => "Testing")
    course.enabled = true
    course.save

```
active_courses = Course.where(:enabled => true)
active_courses.length.should eql 1
```

end
...

i get the following error

1) Course check for active courses after enabling a course
     Failure/Error: active_courses.length.should eql 1

```
   expected: 1
        got: 0

   (compared using eql?)
 # ./course_spec.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

why is the Course.where method return no objects? when i do this in rails console it works fine.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked whether you have any courses at all, enabled or not? Also, this test seems to depend on your database server. Is your server up when you run the test? It would probably help to know what version of rails you are using and what version of what database.

Comment: i'm using SQLite and Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Are you running rails console in the `test` mode or in the `development` mode? Keep in mind that rails for testing and developing an application uses different databases.
Make sure that before the test all records are prepared and stored in the database. For this purpose you could use fixtures or factories (`factory_girl` for example).

ps.
Instead `active_courses.length.should eql 1` you can use `active_courses.should have(1).item` which is more readable.